# What problems are easier assuming zeros of a zeta function don’t behave as we expect?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, big-list

What are some examples of problems which are easier to solve assuming zeros of zeta functions lie off the critical line or do not have expected vertical distribution.

There are some very well known ones such as oscillations in error terms in PNT or using Landau-Siegel zeros to construct sieve weights. What else is out there?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125276/good-uses-of-siegel-zeros

Comment: Thanks for this, please see the edit